# Make Excel Chart filter always visible

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Click in the chart area of an Excel chart and one of the buttons that appears in the top right is a filter (just below a paintbrush and a plus sign – see screenshot below).  Clicking it opens a filter, but as soon as the filter is applied or the user clicks elsewhere the filter disappears.

How can we keep that filter control open and visible whenever the chart sheet is visible?

[image: Screenshot of Excel chart filter]